# Cassandra - Delete Old Versions of Tables and Backup Database

Tags: linux, azure, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Looking in my keyspace directory I see several versions of most of my tables. I am assuming this is because I dropped them at some point and recreated them as I was refining the schema.

```
table1-b3441432142142sdf02328914104803190
table1-ba234143018dssd810412asdfsf2498041
```

These created tables names are very cumbersome to work with. Try changing to one of the directories without copy pasting the directory name from the terminal window... Painful. So easy to mistype something.

That side note aside, **how do I tell which directory is the most current version of the table?** **Can I automatically delete the old versions?** *I am not clear if these are considered snapshots or not since each directory also can contain snapshots*. I read in another post you can stop autosnapshot, but I'm not sure I want that. I'd rather just automatically delete any tables not being currently used (i.e.: that are not the latest version).

I stumbled across this trying to do a backup. I realized I am forced go to every table directory and copy out the snapshot files (there are like 50 directories..not including all the old table versions) which seems like a terrible design (maybe I'm missing something??).

I assumed I could do a snapshot of the whole keyspace and get one file back or at least output all the files to a single directory that represents the snapshot of the entire keyspace. At the very least it would be nice knowing what the current versions are so I can grab the correct files and offload them to storage somewhere.

DataStax Enterprise has a backup feature but it only supports AWS and I am using Azure.

So to clarify:

- How do I automatically delete old table versions and know which is
  the current version?
- How can I backup the most recent versions of the tables and output the files to a **single** directory that I can offload somewhere? I only have two nodes, so simply relying on the repair is not a good option for me if a node goes down.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the active version of a table by looking in the system keyspace and checking the cf_id field.  For example, to see the version for a table in the 'test' keyspace with table name 'temp', you could do this:

```
cqlsh> SELECT cf_id FROM system.schema_columnfamilies WHERE keyspace_name='test' AND columnfamily_name='temp' allow filtering;

 cf_id
--------------------------------------
 d8ea9830-20e9-11e5-afc0-c381f961c62a
```

As far as I know, it is safe to delete (rm -r) outdated table version directories that are no longer active.  I imagine they don't delete them automatically so that you can recover the data if you dropped them by mistake.  I don't know of a way to have them removed automatically even if auto snapshot is disabled.

I don't think there is a command to write all the snapshot files to a single directory.  According to the documentation on snapshot, "After the snapshot is complete, you can move the backup files to another location if needed, or you can leave them in place."  So it's left up to the application developer how they want to handle archiving the snapshot files.

Comment: So I have to run a query for every table.. manually change to each directory based on the id that is returned and copy the files out manually to some folder to I can move them to another location? So if I have 50 tables, I have to run 50 queries and change directories 50 times.. .and perform 50 copy operations? There must be a better way or this is just a terrible design. I get people wanting to restore a single table, but doing all of this to backup a whole keyspace seems absurd. I am wondering if I drain the node and then just copy the whole data directory if it would restore correctly.

Comment: You could probably write a script to clean up old table directories, and another script to copy your snapshots off cluster if that's your normal workflow.  For the open source Cassandra I don't think ease of backups has been a priority, so you may have to build your own helper scripts.